# ajax posting formdata error status 200 OK

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload file using `Ajax`.

The `Error status` is `200` `ok` .

Response text is my `MasterPage` `HTML` Code.

The Request never went to the **Back-end** as i am debugging with a breakpoint into the method.

so far i have tried this.

**C# WebMethod**

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Upload()
        {


            for (int i = 0; i <   Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }

        }`
```

**Ajax Request**

```
function uploadFiles() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        $.each(files, function (key, value) {
            formData.append(key, value);

        });
        $.ajax({
            async: false,   
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home.aspx/Upload',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout :5000,
            success: function (response) {
                alert('succes!!');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("errror");
                console.log(error);
            }
        });


    }
});
```

Comment: If you place a breakpoint at  `Request.Files.Count`, what is the value of `Request.Files`?

Comment: the breakpoint is not triggering at all @G.Hunt

Comment: Have you added the attribute `[WebMethod()]` to the `Upload()` method?

Comment: i tried that  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] and same problem

Comment: Inside ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs, try changing `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;` to `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;`, and see what that does.

Comment: i dont Have RouteConfig i think i need controller ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in ajax call you have to  delete `dataType: json` because files must be  sent `multipart/form-data`

```
function uploadFiles() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function (key, value) {
        formData.append(key, value);

    });
    $.ajax({
        async: false,   
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home.aspx/Upload',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout :5000,
        success: function (response) {
            alert('succes!!');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("errror");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });


}
```

});

Comment: this did Work  !! but my other problem is CodeBehind i added checkPoint into Upload Method and its never Triggering Have any idea why ?

Comment: I was getting the response always in "error:" section of the Ajax even though the server side code complete without any issues; adding the "async: false" from above code fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
 function getBase64(file) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     reader.onload = function () {
        return reader.result;
     };
     reader.onerror = function (error) {
        return '';
     };
 }

 function uploadFiles() {
         var files=[];
         $.each(files, function (key, value) {
             var x=getBase64(value)
             if(!!x)
               files.push(x);
         });
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/Home.aspx/Upload',
             data: JSON.stringity({files:files}),
             dataType: 'json',
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             success: function (response) {
                 alert('succes!!');
             },
             error: function (error) {
                 alert("errror");
                 console.log(error);
             }
         });
     }
 });


 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static void Upload(string[] files)
 {    
     //Convert base64 to file format and save         

 }
```

Comment: wait I got the issue, I am updating the answer.

Comment: code will work now, because I used this code for my project yesterday.

Comment: I had to Remove DataType : 'Json' 
and no more Error  ,, but I have the other Problem and that The code behind I have breakPoint on the Upload Method and it never triggers

Comment: yes everything is working fine i have more than that webmethod and everything is working ok  somehow ! i think the problem is because the web method should be static But When  i static that webmethod then the Scope to Request Class is undifined !!

Comment: now check with WebMethod attribute and static modifier.   In this method you don't need Request.Files